# Is it correct to write a noun once while listing two related (verbs) activities?

Tags: grammar, verbs, nouns

For instance, in the sentence:

> Without adding new items and modifying existing items.

Would it be correct to completely remove the first reference to the noun items? as in:

> Without adding new and modifying existing items.

It sounds wrong. Is the only correct alternative replacing the explicit noun with an implicit reference as in:

> Without adding new items and modifying existing ones.

Is there a more elegant way to avoid writing the explicit noun twice in this sentence?

I read this: [Mixing adjective and noun enumerations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100484/mixing-adjective-and-noun-enumerations) but did not find it very useful.

Comment: In general, it's stylistically clumsy to omit the noun when you're modifying it with two or more *multi-word* elements. So it's okay to speak of, say, *validating new and existing items*, or *adding and modifying items*, but in your version it's probably better to repeat "items". You're simply mistaken in assuming it's not "elegant" to do this (the reverse, in fact).

Comment: So: Without adding new items nor modifying existing ones.

Comment: In your specific context, I would say so, yes. But dump ***nor*** - at best it's "stilted" here, without the support of a preceding ***neither***. The choice between ***and*** and ***or*** is to some extent stylistic, but really turns on whether you're thinking of the two possible actions as "two sides of the same coin" (use ***and***) or as "related, but distinct" (use ***or***). I would *definitely* ignore bib's advice re the comma (to be "valid" it would probably require another one after *existing*), but I guess everyone's entitled to their own opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the addition of a comma would help

> Without adding new, or modifying existing items.

The comma introduces a slight pause that suggests the missing, but implied *items*.

You will note that I substituted *or* for *and*. While the context is not provided, your example seems to suggest neither of the two conditions will occur. If you were to use *and*, it might be ambiguous and could be taken to mean neither would happen or that the concurrence of both would not happen.

Comment: Is this proper English though?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like: "Without adding or modifying new or existing items respectively.".

Comment: This is very suitable.